# Regular expression - string contains a “*” in between every alphabet, but starting and ending with alphabet only

Tags: c#, regex

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(c1,@"^[A-Za-z]([\*][a-z])*[A-Za-z]+$"))

    {
        return true;
    }
```

I am trying to write regular expression which specifies that text should start with a letter and end with a letter and it contains "*" in between every alphabet. I don't know how to specify special character in between every alphabet.

Comment: What happens with two non alpha characters?  Would there _not_ be a star in between them?

Comment: *"I don't know how to specify special character in between every alphabet"* isn't clear at all, show example**s** of correct and incorrect inputs.

Comment: correct form is "CSaSrSaScStSeSr"   here i cannot put star in between every character. So, for example i put "S" instead of special character star

Comment: @Gayathri: are uppercase letters allowed in the middle of the string?

Comment: @Gayathri: Your regex is almost correct. I think you need [`@"\A[A-Za-z](?:\*[a-zA-Z])*\z"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cA%5bA-Za-z%5d%28%3f%3a%5c*%5ba-zA-Z%5d%29*%5cz&i=A*x*c) - it will match any ASCII letter and then 0+ sequences of `*` followed with 1 ASCII letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think you are looking for:

```
^[A-Za-z](?:(?:\*[a-z])*\*[A-Za-z])?$
```

if uppercase letters are allowed in the middle of the string, you can use this funny way:

```
^(?!.*\B)[A-Za-z*]+$
```

*(The negative lookahead `(?!.*\B)` prevents the string to contain a non-word boundary)*

Comment: Except for the fact that the input string can end with a `"\n"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: No, it's a pcre particularity, but `$` doesn't match before a trailing newline character in .net: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.%24&i=a%0d%0a

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: RegexStorm uses `\r\n` line breaks. The behavior is the same as in PCRE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right, I added a `\r` and it matches.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

`^[a-zA-Z](?:\*[a-zA-Z])+$`

This will look for the first character at the start of the string, and then look for all combinations of `*` followed by a letter.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NlyAyz/2)